# How to add all values of edittexts in recyclerview to a textview?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

1. adding all edittexts' value in a textview. edittexts are in recyclerview.
2. deleting item on clicking minus button.
3. adding an item on clicking plus button.
4. only last button will display plus. all other items will display minus sign.

[image: Invoice Screen]

Comment: It's great that you solved your own problem, but questions posted here need to be answerable by other people. As this stands, there is no problem statement and no useful information for anyone to work off of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AdapterMain.java**

```html
package com.demoproject;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by raghav on 10-03-2016.
 */
public class AdapterMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMain.DataObjectHolder> {
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
    private ArrayList<ModelMain> modelMains;

    public AdapterMain(ArrayList<ModelMain> modelMains) {
        this.modelMains = modelMains;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        AdapterMain.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelMains.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_main_list, parent, false);

        return new DataObjectHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.listenerService.updatePosition(position);
        holder.listenerPrice.updatePosition(position);

        holder.edService.setText(modelMains.get(position).getService());

        holder.edPrice.setText("" + modelMains.get(position).getPrice());
        if (modelMains.get(position).isBtnPlus()){
            holder.btnAdd.setText("+");
            holder.btnAdd.setBackground(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_design_plus));
        }else {
            holder.btnAdd.setText("-");
            holder.btnAdd.setBackground(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_design_minus));
        }
    }

    public void addItem(ModelMain modelMain, int index) {
        modelMains.add(modelMain);
        if (index !=0 ){
            modelMains.get(index-1).setBtnPlus(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        if (modelMains.size() > index){
            modelMains.remove(index);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            totalPrice();
        }
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {

        private int position;
        private EditText editText;

        public MyCustomEditTextListener(EditText ed) {
            this.editText = ed;
        }
        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            if (charSequence.length() == 0){
                return;
            }

            if (editText.getId() == R.id.txtPrice){
                if (String.valueOf(modelMains.get(position).getPrice()).equals(charSequence.toString())){
                    return;
                }else {
                    modelMains.get(position).setPrice(Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString()));
                    totalPrice();
                }
            }else if (editText.getId() == R.id.txtService){
                if (modelMains.get(position).getService().equals(charSequence.toString())){
                    return;
                }else {
                    modelMains.get(position).setService(charSequence.toString());
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    }

    private void totalPrice() {
        int price=0;
        for (int j = 0;j<modelMains.size();j++){
            price+=modelMains.get(j).getPrice();
        }

        MainActivity.txtTotalPrice.setText(""+price);
    }

    public class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        EditText edService, edPrice;
        Button btnAdd;
        LinearLayout linBtn;
        MyCustomEditTextListener listenerPrice,listenerService;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            edService = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtService);
            edPrice = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            btnAdd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            linBtn = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linBtn);
            linBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.listenerPrice = new MyCustomEditTextListener(this.edPrice);
            this.listenerService = new MyCustomEditTextListener(this.edService);
            this.edPrice.addTextChangedListener(listenerPrice);
            this.edService.addTextChangedListener(listenerService);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.demoproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView tableList;
    ArrayList<ModelMain> modelMains;
    private AdapterMain adapterMain;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public static TextView txtTotalPrice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Create An Initial Invoice");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tableList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tableList);
        tableList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        txtTotalPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalPrice);

        findViewById(R.id.btnNext).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });

        modelMains = new ArrayList<>();

        adapterMain = new AdapterMain(modelMains);

        tableList.setAdapter(adapterMain);

        adapterMain.addItem(new ModelMain("",0,true),modelMains.size());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapterMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterMain.MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                if (modelMains.get(position).isBtnPlus()){
                    adapterMain.addItem(new ModelMain("",0,true),modelMains.size());
                }else {
                    adapterMain.deleteItem(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Estimated Job Time"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/tableList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="right">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textSize="25sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTotalPrice"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" AED"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add Note"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Write Few Words About Services To Be Done By You"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:text="Submit To Customer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_main_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linPrimary"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtService"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_design"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_design"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linBtn">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design_plus"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**button_design_plus.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**rectangle_design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Stack Snippets are for *browser-runnable* code, only; JS, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: okay i didn't know that but just it was looking great this way and copying from it was also easy so..

Comment: No worries. For future reference you can copy all code into your question, select it, and press CTRL + K to indent it without using the Stack Snippet option.

Comment: isBtnPlus 
is this the button you have defined in ModelClass???
please tell this.

Comment: @amitpandya its just a boolean and not a whole view of a button. it preserves if button indicates plus or minus

Comment: I do not understand how you are fetching data from TypeCast and Service in activity ? Can you please explain me. Thank in advance.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. I am not fetching data from service. @DynamicMind